# WPF Progressbar with two states (busy and progress)

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a simple program which has two long running tasks to perform:

1. copying a lot of folders containing databases
2. working with those copied databases.

What I want to do is the following: 
These long running process run in an extra thread with different variables which update my GUI - so for example the current progress bar is working, also all messages I need to show on the GUI. 
However, at the moment, I can use the progress bar only for the second task (working with the databases) - the copying of the folders and files is done in a recoursive way (calling itself for every subfolder, that needs to be copied) and I don't know how many folders will be copied. 
Therefore while the copying is going on, I want the progress bar to show a busy indication (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L_Sv10Mpb0) one), and after it's finished it should be a standard progress bar for the work on the dbs.

Is such a solution possible in a clean way?

Comment: +one follow-up question:
I also have a message: "copying folders and files...".
It would be nice to indicate that the program is working by changing the ellipsis every second or so like this:
"copying folders and files"
"copying folders and files."
"copying folders and files.."
"copying folders and files..."

I know this can be done with timers and updating the corresponding string, but that seems a bit complex/impractical to me for such a simple task. Is there no build in solution for this?

Comment: Could you share relevant code?

Comment: Please, read this: [About Progress Bar Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760816(v=vs.85).aspx) and this: [How to: Create a ProgressBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743674(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `WPF`, the `ProgressBar` has a property `IsIndeterminate` which does exactly this.

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

When set to true, the the progress bar will infinitely 'spin' and will not show progress within a range.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for maybe asking obvious questions...this is my first program in c#^^